# por que no puedo imprimir mis datos como un vector

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo txt que solo posee numeros `1,2,6,6,5,4,6,2`
pero al ingresarlos al vector me imprime los numeros las veces que yo le indico; el código está así:

```
List<string> nombres = new List<string> ( );

             StreamReader file = new StreamReader ( @"C: \Users\franc\Documents\Tarea.txt" );


                while (!file.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string x = file.ReadLine ( );
                    nombres.Add ( x );
                string[] num = new string[tamaño];
                for(int k = 0; k < tamaño; k++)
                {
                    num[k] = x;
                }
                int n = 0;
                for (; n < tamaño; n++)
                {
                    Console.Write ( "{0}", num[n] );
                }
```

en el momento de imprimir me imprime los numeros pero repetidos por las veces que yo le digo. Ejemplo es que me pide el tamaño que yo le asginaré al vector si le pongo 10 entonces cada numero me lo imprime 10 veces y no es eso lo que busco sino que solo me imprima los numeros hasta llegar al límite. ¿En qué estoy mal?

Comment: Como guardas los numeros en el fichero: separados por coma o uno debajo del otro.

Comment: en num[k]=x estás guardando la misma linea para todos  los k; Que valor puede tomar la variable tamaño? ¿por qué tu arreglo es de tipo string? nombres.Add(x) con  qué propósito es? ¿la linea contiene numeros separados por coma? Si pones  tamaño 10 debería imprimir los primeros 10 digitos de la linea puestos en un  vector? ¿Donde termina el while?¿Por cada linea leida debes repetir el proceso?

Comment: los separo por comas y luego los trato de enviar al vector usando la coma como separador de variable pero ahi no entiendo del todo

Comment: Revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: Si hubo alguna respuesta que resolvió tu problema marcala como aceptada y si hubo otras que te ayudaron dales un voto, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
var texto = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\fichero.txt");//Esto es una ruta de ejemplo, la tuya será diferente
var numeros = texto.Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","").Split(',').Take(tamanno);

foreach (var n in numeros)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Número: {0}", n);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Para lograr lo que pides usamos el **método** **ReadAllText** de la **clase** **File**, este método recibe como parámetro la ruta del fichero  y devuelve un **string** con toda la información contenida en el fichero.

Posteriormente viene esta línea de código:

```
var numeros = texto.Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","").Split(',').Take(tamanno);
```

La cual va a quitarnos todos los caracteres **tabuladores("\r") y saltos de línea("\n")** y nos va a guardar en un arreglo cada número del fichero, usando la **función** **Split** y como caracter separador la **coma(,)**.

Para obtener solamente un subgrupo de tu arreglo usas la **función Take**, la cual recibe como parámetro un entero que es la cantidad de elementos del vector original, que quieres obtener.

Posteriormente hacemos un **ciclo foreach** para recorrer el arreglo obtenido e imprimir cada posición del arreglo.

Para usar la **clase** **File** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.IO;
```

Y para usar el **método Take**, debes poner en los **usings**;

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: si yo puedo hacer esto y esta muy bien pero en mi ejercicio me pide que yo almacene los datos de txt en un vector para luego imprimir el vector seria algo asi en el txt yo tengo 1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,4 tengo 9 numeros en el txt y al iniciar el porgrama indicarle que quiero que me muestre un vector de 6 espacios y que me imprima solo 6 datos de ese txt que en el vector lleguen los datos asi [0]=1,[1]=2, [2]=2, [3]=4, [4]=5, [5]=5 eso es lo que no entiendo si lo hago con el ciclo for me ingresa todos los datos en cada posicion del vector y ahi esta mi error

Comment: @FJAB, revisa lo nuevo que puse

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te pongo una vesión modificada de tu programa donde lo unico que cambia es cuando creas la variable num, en vez de hacerlos a new string[] lo hacemos a  un x.Split.

1. Versión modificada (mínimo cambio) estas haciendolo bien.

```
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"C: \Users\franc\Documents\Tarea.txt");


    while (!file.EndOfStream) {
        string x = file.ReadLine();
        nombres.Add(x);

        //  Separamos los numeros

        string[] num = x.Split(';');
// De aqui 
//     Si aún quieres crear tu vector entonces
// descomenta las lineas siguientes y comentas  la  de arriba
//      var numsX = x.Split(';'); 
//      string[] num=new string[tamaño];
//      for (int k = 0; k < tamaño; k++)
//      {
//          num[k] = numsX[k];
//  }
// Hasta aqui ya lo hizo el Split porlo tanto se comentan
        int n = 0;
        for (; n < tamaño; n++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", num[n]);
        }

    }
```

2. Una alternativa para veas otras formas de hacerlo

```
    List<string> nombres = new List<string>();

    // Leemos  todo el archivo
    string[] lineas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C: \Users\franc\Documents\Tarea.txt"); 
    // Recorremos linea x linea
    foreach(var  linea in lineas) {
        // En linea tenemos la lista de numeros  separados por punto coma
        // Aprovechamos  que están  separador por ; para dividirlos usando un split(';')
        var numeros = linea.Split(';');
        // En este punto numeros  es un arreglo de n-1 numeros 
        // Imprimimos los primeros "tamaño" numeros
        for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
            Console.
        }
    }


    // Por último , guardamos los registros en  nombres
    nombres.AddRange(lineas);
```

Espero puede ayudarte.

Answer (score -1):

Tu programa hace eso por que eso es lo que le estas indicando,la logica de tu código es esa, coloco a continuación tu codigo comentado para indicarte donde esta el error.

```
 List<string> nombres = new List<string> ( );   
 StreamReader file = new StreamReader ( @"C: \Users\franc\Documents\Tarea.txt" );
    while (!file.EndOfStream)
    {
       //Lees una linea y estoy suponiendo que contiene solo un componente del vector.
       string x = file.ReadLine ( );
       //Lo agregas a una lista que no se usa para nada en lo adelante
       nombres.Add ( x );
       //Creas un arreglo con capacidad = tamaño
       string[] num = new string[tamaño];
       //Y ahora en el cilclo for agregas al arreglo num  el valor x leido tantas veces como tamaño.
       for(int k = 0; k < tamaño; k++)
       {
           num[k] = x;//Aqui estas agregando el mismo valor tantas veces como sea tamaño al arreglo
       }
       int n = 0;
       for (; n < tamaño; n++)
       {
          Console.Write ( "{0}", num[n] );
       }
   }
```

Suponiendo que desees crear vectores con un tamaño determinado e imprimirlos por pantalla, yo haria lo siguiente.

Primero suponiendo que sea necesario usar un arreglo para almacenar el vector

```
private void ImprimirVectores(int tamaño)
{
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"Tarea.txt");
    string[] num = new string[tamaño];
    int k = 0;
    while (!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        string x = file.ReadLine();
        num[k++] = x;//Agrego la linea actual al vector

        if(k==tamaño)
        {
            //Al haber leido tantas lineas como tamaño imprimimos el vector en una linea de texto separada por punto y coma.
            int n = 0;
              string vector="";
                for (; n < tamaño; n++)
                {
                    vector = vector + " ; " + num[n];
                }
                //Eliminamos el primer caracter qie siempre será una coma
                vector.Remove(0, 1);
                Console.Write("{0}", vector);
            //Inicializamos el vector
            num = new string[tamaño];
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    //A continuación imprimimos el ultimo vector que puede contener un numero menor de componentes que tamaño
    if(k>0)
    {
        int n = 0;
        for (; n < k; n++)
        {
              vector = vector + " ; " + num[n];
        }
        vector.Remove(0, 1);
        Console.Write("{0}", vector);
    }
}
```

Ahora suponiendo que haya que usar un `List<string>` para almacenar el vector, en este caso el código se simplifica en algunos aspectos.

```
   private void ImprimirVectores1(int tamaño)
        {
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"Tarea.txt");
            List<string> nombres = new List<string>();
        while (!file.EndOfStream)
        {
            nombres.Add(file.ReadLine());
            if (nombres.Count == tamaño)
            {
             //Al haber leido tantas lineas como tamaño imprimimos el vector en una linea de texto separada por punto y coma.
                string vector="";
                foreach (string cad in nombres)
                {
                   vector = vector + " ; " +cad;
                }
                //Eliminamos el primer caracter qie siempre será una coma           
                vector.Remove(0, 1);
                Console.Write("{0}", vector);
                //Inicializamos el vector
                nombres.Clear();
            }
        }
       //A continuación imprimimos el ultimo vector que puede contener un numero menor de componentes que tamaño
        if (nombres.Count > 0)
        {
           foreach (string cad in nombres)
           {
            vector = vector + " ; " +cad;
            }
            vector.Remove(0, 1);
           Console.Write("{0}", vector);
        }
    }
```

Comment: al hacerlo asi como tu lo enviaste solo me esta imprimiendo las comas que separan cada numero pero de igual forma sigue imprimiendolas todas son 8 comas y eso me imprime asi le indique cualquier tamaño al vector ya no se que mas hacerle

Comment: Tienes razon, edito la repuesta para resolver ese problema.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que he colocado una repuesta, en la que se supone que cada linea, almacenada en el archivo es un componente del vector, por que eso es los que se puede presumir a partir de lo que intentaste hacer. Cuando se trabaja con datos almacenados en archivos de texto plano, tanto al guardar los datos, como al recuperarlos hay que ser muy estrictos en la logica de programación. Si fuera el caso por ejemplo, que tu archivo, guardara los componentes de un vector en una misma linea, separados por comas, la logica de programación seria otra muy diferente y mi código no serviria para eso.